# FOSUserBundle: two login templates for the the login action

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed `FOSUserBundle`. Now I would like to have two different templates for the same login action: one for the login in the layout and the other one for a standalone login page.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: we need more than that. For example, which one of those would be primary?

Comment: @JovanPerovic I don't know :) anyone maybe..One of them is in the layout (header) and the other one is a standalone login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the login form from FOSUserBundle as is (or overwrite it by moving it to app/Resources). This form will be used for the standalone login page. For other sections of the website you can create a new login form in twig yourself, the important thing is that your form will need to have all the fields named like the one from FOSUserBundle and to have the action path set to the login check page (because your using FOSUserBundle the path is "fos_user_security_check").

The names for the fields you will find here:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig

You can see that you need also a generated csrfToken. You can generate it in your controller, also inspired by the guys from FOSUserBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L43

Comment: thanks, your explanation is clear! Instead of generate the csft_token inside the controller, I have genereted directly from the template: `{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}`. Is this ok also? It seems it is working.

Comment: Yeah, it is even better to generate it directly in twig. Glad it helped